# Nginx location redirecting improperly

Tags: nginx, redhat, ruby-on-rails

My nginx.conf:

```
http {
  include mime.types;

  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # click tracking!
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log combined;

  sendfile on;

  tcp_nopush on; # off may be better for *some* Comet/long-poll stuff
  tcp_nodelay off; # on may be better for some Comet/long-poll stuff

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.0;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_min_length 500;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;



  upstream nvhbase {
    server unix:///tmp/nvhbase.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  upstream tracker {
    server unix:///tmp/tracker.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {

    listen 80;
    server_name hmaapp101;

    # Application root, as defined previously
    #root /var/www/nvh/public;
    #try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri;
    location / {
        root /var/www/nvh/public;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/nvhbase.sock;
    }

    location ^~ /tracker/ {
        root /var/www/tracker/public;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:///tmp/tracker.sock:/tracker/;
    }
  }
}
```

When I go to `http://myapp/tracker` I get redirected to `myapp/tracker/tracker/users/sign_in` instead of `myapp/tracker/users/sign_in`.

I have tried a million variations, but either get a 500 too many redirects, or this.

I changed a few things fiddling around, thought I changed it back, but now I've broken something...shoulda backed up.

Please assist. Is this bad practice to run two rails apps like this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `root` in the `server` block, not in the `location` block. This is one of the most common nginx mistakes.

In the `location` where you need to override the document root, use `alias` instead of `root` so that the path is translated properly.

Comment: And what should the root be?? `/var/www/`? Is this the source of my weird redirects?

Comment: The root should be your document root, as given by the application you're running.

Comment: Changed root to alias, no change in behavior.